# WKWebView iOS 10.3 auto full screen videos regardless of WKWebViewConfiguration in iOS 10.3. Any work arounds?

Tags: c#, ios, swift, xamarin

I have a tableview where every cell has either an image, video, or gif. I am using WKWebView to render the url regardless of what it is. Videos I want to have ability to play inline or full screen but required user interaction.

In iOS 10.2 this was working but now in iOS 10.3 regardless of what is in the `WKWebViewConfiguration` it will repeatedly auto full screen videos when they come onscreen in the table view.

I am programing in Xamarin with C# but the syntax is very similar to Swift.
Has any one else encountered this issue? Has anyone come up with a work around? The only thing I can think of is straight up not using WKWebView as a control.

```
var webConfig = new WKWebViewConfiguration()
{
    MediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = true,
    AllowsInlineMediaPlayback = true,
    AllowsPictureInPictureMediaPlayback = true,
    MediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback = WKAudiovisualMediaTypes.All
};
var webView = new WKWebView(new CGRect(), webConfig);
webView.AllowsLinkPreview = true;
webView.ClipsToBounds = true;
webView.ScrollView.ScrollEnabled = false;
```